# Why is my interval calling my function even though its in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a stopwatch that has buttons to start, stop, and reset the time. I assigned an interval to a variable to pause it using clearInterval every time I click the stop button, but my interval is  calling the function even though I clicked no button. How do I fix this?

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
const resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');

const myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10);
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setInterval(setTime, 10);
})
stopButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
})

const timeUnits = ['00', '00', '00', '00'];
milliSeconds = 0;
seconds = 0;
minutes = 0;
hours = 0;

function setTime() {
  if (minutes == 60) {
    hours++;
    minutes = 0;
    timeUnits[0] = hours;
    timeUnits[1] = 0;
  } else if (seconds == 60) {
    minutes++;
    seconds = 0;
    timeUnits[1] = minutes;
    timeUnits[3] = 0;
  } else if (milliSeconds == 100) {
    seconds++;
    milliSeconds = 0;
    timeUnits[2] = seconds
    timeUnits[3] = 0;
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = timeUnits.join(':');
  } else {
    milliSeconds++;
    timeUnits[3] = milliSeconds;
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = timeUnits.join(':');
  };
}
```

```html
<p id="para">00:00:00:00</p>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You set up the interval in two places:

```js
const myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10);     // <-- Here (A)
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setInterval(setTime, 10);                      // <-- and here (B)
})
```

In spot A (auto-start on page load) you save the interval ID into `myInterval` so that you can later do `clearInterval(myInterval)`.

However, in spot B (on-demand start on "start" button click), you do *not* do that, so the interval set by clicking the "start" button can never be cleared.

This can be fixed by saving the interval into `myInterval` in both places:

```js
let myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10)
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10)
})
```

Now, this created a bit of duplicate code, which is not ideal, and also there is still the problem that just clicking "start" multiple times would create multiple intervals running in parallel, overwriting the previous interval ID with the new one, making the old intervals again unclearable.

My suggestion for solving both of these issues is to create functions `startInterval` and `stopInterval`, where `startInterval` would also first call `stopInterval` before setting up a new interval, and `stopInterval` clearing the old one if it exists. Then you can call `startInterval` both on page load and on "start" button click, and `stopInterval` on "stop" button click:

```js
let myInterval = null

function startInterval () {
  stopInterval()
  myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10)
}

function stopInterval () {
  if (!myInterval) return
  clearInterval(myInterval)
  myInterval = null
}

startInterval()

startButton.addEventListener('click', startInterval)
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopInterval)
```

From the wording of the question I'm not sure whether you really want to auto-start the timer though. In case you don't, you can simply remove the `startInterval()` line from my example (or in case of the original code, change the first assignment to `let myInterval = null` like in the second example).

Comment: The sanity checks you added are a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```js
const myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10);
```

actually starts the interval.

You need to change it to this:

```js
let myInterval;
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myInterval = setInterval(setTime, 10);
})
```

This ensures that everytime you press the `start` button the interval will be assigned to the `myInterval` variable again which can then be cleared by the stop button